# How to loop through the date range in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I get the start date (2017-09-14) and end date(2017-09-16) and want to loop through the date range to get the month and year for comparison. How can I do that?

```
[ ...document.getElementsByClassName("event_date") 
].forEach( el => { 
const result = el.textContent.split("to"); 
const startday = result[0].split("-"); 
const endday = result[1].split("-"); 

if( startday[1] != {{:charmonths[month]}} || startday[2] != {{: year}} )
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do by adding one day to the current which causes the date to roll over to the next month.

```
let endDate = new Date(); // today
let startDate = new Date(2017, 0, 1); // Jan 1st 2017
let daysOfYear = [];
for (let day = startDate;day <= endDate; day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1)) {
     daysOfYear.push(new Date(day)); 
}
```

Simple.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: How to combine with startday and endday?

Comment: In my example, startday is 1-1-2017 and enddate is today, you can combine this way.

Comment: I have updated the answer combining start and end date

Comment: I'm getting an error: day.getDate is not a function.